# Compare rows pandas values and see if they match python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do some comparations between rows values in a pandas dataframe and see if they match and if they do not. If they match I need to print out and Ok and if they do not I need to print out the complete rows values to the user to verify. There´s not pattern to decide which value it will be the correct to compare to, it just need to print out the values if just one row value do not match with the others.

```
Data:
      df1      df2      df3
  A   6004     6004     6004
  B   1501     1401     1502
  C   200      200      200
  D   101      110      102

Expected output:
The values from A in all datafrafames are correct.
The values from C in all dataframes are correct.

The values from B are:
1501 in df1, 1401 in df2, 1502 in df3
Check your data before compare.

The values from D are:
101 in df1, 110 in df2, 102 in df3
Check your data before compare.
```

There is a big dataframe and I need to print out all the corrects and all the incorrects so I need to be the fast as possible and I would like it to be as a function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward with `iterrows` and `iteritems`:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.nunique()==1: 
        print(f'The values from {idx} in all datarfames are correct')
    else:
        print(f'The values from {idx} are:')
        print(', '.join(f'{v} in {c}' for v,c in row.iteritems()))
        print('Check your data before compare')
    print()
```

Output:

```
The values from A in all datarfames are correct

The values from B are:
df1 in 1501, df2 in 1401, df3 in 1502
Check your data before compare
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I implement this as a function to return all the strings at once? @QuangHoang