# Validating horizontal row data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, validation

I come here to ask for help. I'm working with data like:

```
df1:
      name   name1   name2
A      13     13      13
B      13     27      57
C      12     12      12
D      26     23       2
```

I'm trying to use a code like:

```
def val(df):
    ret = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.nunique()==1:
           ret.append(f'The values of {idx} in name, name1, name2 are corrects')
        else:
           ret(["".join(f'*The values in {idx} are:', 
           ', '.join(f'{c} in {v}' for v,c in row.iteritems()),
           'Check your data before compare.']))
    return ret
```

The issue here is that, is not working well. First, I need to get the results as string not as a list. I know it could be possible with `"".join()` but when I try the code, I just get the last result and not the whole answers that I want.
Please, how can get the full answers?. I would like to see more options and not just one.

```
Example:
-The values of A in name, name1, name3 are corrects. 
- The values in B are:
  13 in name, 27 in name3 and 57 in name2.
  Check your data before compare.
-The values of C in name, name1, name3 are corrects.
- The values in D are:
  26 in name, 23 in name3 and 2 in name2.
  Check your data before compare.
```

Comment: If the number of your columns and their names are fixed, why insist on using `str.join`? Couldn't you just make a fixed string template and fill the three numbers in?

Comment: @BillHuang Thanks for comment. Can you show me?

Comment: Your function has syntax and other errors please fix and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def val(df):
    ret = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.nunique() == 1:
            ret.append(f'- The values of {idx} in name, name1, name2 are corrects')
        else:
            ret.append(
                f"- The values in {idx} are:\n"\             
                f"  {row[0]} in name, {row[1]} in name1, {row[2]} in name2.\n"\
                "  Check your data before compare."
            )
    return ret    
ans = val(df)
```

**output**

```
for i in ans:
    print(i)

- The values of A in name, name1, name2 are corrects
- The values in B are:
  13 in name, 27 in name1, 57 in name2.
  Check your data before compare.
- The values of C in name, name1, name2 are corrects
- The values in D are:
  26 in name, 23 in name1, 2 in name2.
  Check your data before compare.
```

Comment: Hi @BillHuang. Thanks for your answer. I'm tying to return the values as they are in the output but I just get the last value. Why is that?

Comment: I just try to transform to a function. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395801/compare-rows-pandas-values-and-see-if-they-match-python) as a print out but I need it as a function with the output you just show.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. First, I did provide a function. Second, the function produced a list containing all the output strings you expected. What exact output are you expecting? Can you exemplify explicitly in detail?

Comment: I don´t want to bother, everything is just fine. I'm just trying the function you provide and I get just the last element from the list. My question is, why is happening that?.

Comment: No. You must have messed your code up elsewhere beyond the scope of what you have presented in this post. I have reproduced with my code that `len(ans) = 4` and  `ans[0], ans[1], ... ans[3]` are all intact. I cannot debug something I can't see (or foresee).

Comment: Yes. It was a mistake I made. I was positioning the `ret list` inside the loop. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Just please show exactly what you're trying next time.

Answer (score 0):

How about composing your string as part of the `np.where` clause, like so.

All the other answers copy your original approach of iterating through rows which is inefficient beyond a toy dataset. `np.where` is a vectorised operation so will be much faster and its logic is more straightforward than a custom function. The only caveat is that string interpolation won't work here hence the slightly awkward multi-line syntax.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
index  name   name1   name2
A      13     13      13
B      13     27      57
C      12     12      12
D      26     23       2
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True, index_col="index")

results = np.where(
    df.nunique(axis=1) == 1,
    'The values in ' + df.index + ' in name, name1, name2 are the same\n',
    'The values in ' + df.index + ' are:\n' + \
    df["name"].astype(str)  + ' in name, ' + \
    df["name1"].astype(str) + ' in name1, ' + \
    df["name2"].astype(str) + ' in name2.\nCheck your data.\n'
)

print(*results, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {'A': 13, 'B': 13, 'C': 12, 'D': 26},
                   'name1': {'A': 13, 'B': 27, 'C': 12, 'D': 23},
                   'name2': {'A': 13, 'B': 57, 'C': 12, 'D': 2}})
```

Hard to know how to correct your function as it has numerous errors.

You can use a Pandas Series like a dictionary with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```
In [25]: s = '{name:} in name, {name1:} in name1, {name2:} in name2'

In [26]: row = df.loc['A',:]

In [27]: print(s.format(**row))
13 in name, 13 in name1, 13 in name2

In [28]: for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     print(idx, s.format(**row))
    ...:     
A 13 in name, 13 in name1, 13 in name2
B 13 in name, 27 in name1, 57 in name2
C 12 in name, 12 in name1, 12 in name2
D 26 in name, 23 in name1, 2 in name2
```

Same thing using a formatted string literal ([f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)).

```
In [29]: for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     print(idx, f'''{row['name']} in name, {row['name1']} in name1, {row['name2']} in name2''')
    ...:     
A 13 in name, 13 in name1, 13 in name2
B 13 in name, 27 in name1, 57 in name2
C 12 in name, 12 in name1, 12 in name2
D 26 in name, 23 in name1, 2 in name2
```